# How to package an Akka project

Tags: java, maven, akka

I have an Akka stand alone project

that implements the Bootable interface of the mico-kernel

The tutorials on paclaging an akka system with the micro-kernel

describes an SBT project that uses the sbt pluggin

Can nay one tell me how to package the maven project with the micro-kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search on Google for "akka microkernel maven" lists this as one of the top contending answers to your question: http://jcranky.com/2012/07/13/akka-microkernel-with-maven/

Comment: `Not Found

The requested URL /2012/07/13/akka-microkernel-with-maven/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Here's a mirror from Googles cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:J7f_YfAkuc8J:blog.jcranky.com/tag/akka-microkernel/+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=se

Answer (score 0):

after going through JCrnak's blog and reading through the maven assembly plugin and the manifest file documentation,I was able to come up with a slightly different solution from that of JCranky and will like to share.

The first assumption is that all the Akka plugins including that of the microkernel have been configured in the POM.xml. Secondly, that the application to be distributed has been developed.

The maven package phase creates an executable jar file. However this will need the main class of the application to be directly executed using the java -jar command. To make the location of the main class known to the package application , we insert the following plugin with the configuration of the manifest file in the POM.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.bbox.gesture.BoundingBox</mainClass> 
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

To copy the akka dependencies into the lib file in the target file we add the following plugin.

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                          ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

With this plugins we copy all the necessary files to the target file.

Now we copy the content of the target file to a zip folder using the assembly plugin with the descriptor.xml file. below is the descriptor.xml file.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

  <id>akka</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/deploy</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
          <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
          <exclude>*.zip</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>


    <files>
        <file>
            <source>target/com-bbox-gesture-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>/deploy</outputDirectory>
            <destName>bbox.jar</destName>
        </file>

    <file>
      <source>src/main/resources/application.conf</source>
      <outputDirectory>/deploy/config</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>

</assembly>
```

To run the assembly plugin we add the following to the POM.xml

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

To top it all we add a simple batch file that start's the application by running the java -jar command from withing the deploy directory. Below is the simple script from the batch file

```
echo off  
cls  
start java -jar bbox.jar
```

the start command runs the java -jar command on the executable jar file. the bbox.jar file is the executable jar

To run the application simply unpack the zip folder in your server , navigate to the start.bat file and click.